# Can LWP be used to receive form POST data?

Tags: html, perl, lwp

I have a form I have build using `CGI::Application` and `HTML::Template` which contains a HTML form like this

```
<form name="form" action="receiver.pl" method="POST">
```

Now I need to write the `receiver.pl`, and was wondering if `LWP` can be used for this?

Or does the exist a Perl module made especially for getting the POST data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `LWP` is for submitting, not receiving HTTP requests.

For receiving and processing an HTTP request, you can use a module like [`CGI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI), or, yes, [`CGI::Application`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI%3a%3aApplication).